# Stringvar tkinter within Textvariables

Tags: python

I'm trying to create multiple inputs for the user but for some reason it doesn't get the variables and I can't seem to figure it out how to do this.

```
def Updata():
        for r in range(1,5):
            v1list.append(StringVar())
            NameEntry = Entry(root, textvariable=v1list[r-1], bg = bg, fg = fg, font = font, width=20).grid(row = r, column = 0, sticky=W)
    def GetData():
        print(v1list)
```

The output of this script is:

```
[<tkinter.StringVar object at 0x05B6C550>, <tkinter.StringVar object at 0x05B6C630>, <tkinter.StringVar object at 0x05B6C690>, <tkinter.StringVar object at 0x05B6C710>]
```

It should readable text because I'm trying to get the Name and Age of someone they manually enter these in the program.

I know you usually have to do `.get()` but I've no clue on how to implement this with list or if I'm on the right track with setting this up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to understand why it outputs what it does, so I will not address that.
To print each variable individually, you can do:

```
for var in v1list:
  print(var.get())
```

To print them all in 1 list, you can do:

```
print([var.get() for var in v1list])
```

This uses a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).